# Classic GA successful form submission tracking

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to track the form submission using classic GA. If I use event based tracking how can I check if all the form fields are validated before tracking submission button? How these types of logic are added using classic GA?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this. The best option will be determined by your exact setup. Note: From the sound of your question it should be clear that Google Analytics does not validate your forms- it is up to you to do that yourself.

- Use an event listener on the form for `submit`. This will trigger the event when the form is submitted, but your validator may or may not trigger the function when appropriate. However, I like to send an event on `submit` anyway with an action of "Submit (Attempt)", so then you can see how many validation errors are being triggered (and how many users fix them and submit again).
- The next option would be to trigger an event on a submit callback. If your validation can send a callback when it's good, then trigger the event function at that point. This will be the next most accurate method of tracking. One example of how this could be a false positive is if the user loses internet connection while filling out the form. *(Note: This is usually how I do it with my setup)*
- Send a server-side event using the [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide). If you're sending the form to your server, you could send the event when you're absolutely sure it went through. *This is the most complex option, but also the most accurate.*
- Use a Thank You page, and either track pageviews, or just send an event on load.

For reference, here is the syntax for sending an event via Classic Google Analytics:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Category Here', 'Action Here', 'Label Here']);
```